# Moving an object from component to component in order to make changes on that object

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have a html table like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Ime</td>
    <td>Prezime</td>
    <td>Jmbg</td>
    <td>Izmeni</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let osoba of osobe | async">
    <td>{{osoba.ime}}</td>
    <td>{{osoba.prezime}}</td>
    <td>{{osoba.jmbg}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="change 
      (click)="saveSelectedPerson(osoba)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to define the function (click)="saveSelectedPerson" so that on click app goes to another form to change osoba(Person) info of that person, meaning i need to somehow import that particular person into ChangeInfoComponent which is another component this is just the PreviewComponent

I tried creating object in PreviewComponent and assigning the properties from clicked Person , but when i log that (this.goToOsoba) Person is undefined

```
 saveSelectedPerson(o: Osoba) {
     console.log(o);
     console.log(this.goToOsoba);
      this.goToOsoba.ime = o.ime;
      this.goToOsoba.prezime=o.prezime;
      this.goToOsoba.jmbg=o.jmbg;
   }
```

What am i doing wrong ? And is my approach good or sharing object between the component is supposed to be done some other way and not over public properties of component ?

Comment: Have you initialized *goToOsoba* ?

Comment: Yes , goToOsoba : Osobaa;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shared service to store and retrieve information about selected osoba. Save it to service in saveSelectedPerson function, and in ChangeInfoComponent use same service to get that data.
More options you have it here:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: So sharing properties from comp to comp is done over service , thank you sir

Comment: It's one of the options. More you will find in the url